# Are wisdom teeth disappearing?

Tags: evolution, dentistry

I was sent an article (am a bit of a future evolution fan), entitled [5 Signs Humans Are Still Evolving](http://mentalfloss.com/article/30795/5-signs-humans-are-still-evolving), from a website called "MentalFloss" - and as it is not peer-reviewed, I am a bit dubious of its claims, one in particular was:

> One estimate says 35 percent of the population is born without wisdom teeth, and some say they will disappear altogether.

They link to the HowStuffWorks page [Are wisdom teeth becoming obsolete?](http://science.howstuffworks.com/life/evolution/no-wisdom-teeth2.htm), in which there is a lot of uncertainty, but they state:

> Some experts say it's possible these teeth will eventually disappear

Is there any scientific evidence to support the claim that an estimated 35% of the population are born without wisdom teeth, and especially, is there scientific evidence to suggest that they are disappearing in an evolutionary sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that if the claim is tweaked slightly, there is some evidence to support it. Originally it says "*born without wisdom teeth*", which to me sounds like they are missing *all* of their wisdom teeth. I haven't seen any studies that show that high a rate for that. Also, I believe everybody is "born" without them, since they generally don't start forming until age ten or so.

If it's changed to "*will not develop one or more wisdom teeth*", that's a bit easier to find support for. While [this study](http://www.e-jds.com/article/S1991-7902(12)00054-2/pdf) was mainly looking at specific ethnic variations, they also include a table showing various studies done from 1954 to 2010:

[image]

The "Prevalence" column shows the rate where one or more third molars (wisdom teeth) are missing. You can see that only one of them (Lee et al, 2009) tops 35%, but there are several that get somewhat close. So even if 35% is a bit high, it's probably correct to say "One estimate says..."

---

The evolutionary aspect is trickier, but it's clear that the trait is inheritable. Sampling shows that it varies tremendously by ethnicity:

> Based on large samples, agenesis of third molar ranged from 0.2% in Bantu speakers from Angola (6) to nearly 100% in Mexican Indians (7). Evidence supporting a genetic etiology for tooth agenesis and their shape is well established (8–10).

[The study](http://www.pnas.org/content/103/15/5676.full.pdf) that's from goes on to examine specific mutations in the PAX9 gene and their effects relating to dentition, in case you're interested.

Note that it **doesn't** say "they will disappear", just that their formation is based on an inheritable trait. It could go either way from here, as always.

Comment: Is there evidence to suggest they're disappearing: e.g. that there are fewer of them now than there used to be?

Comment: @ChrisW From what I could find, it's hard to tell. It's difficult to get a large number of samples old enough to be certain. In addition, since it's highly variable by ethnicity even today, you need many old samples from distinct groups.

Comment: Thank you @Geobits, the articles I cited and quoted from do seem vague - am glad you found this evidence.